# Creat a confidence interval for non normal data

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I have a data set based on percent time a fleet of machines were available each month, as a result the majority of the observations are close 100 with a few being lower and one or two being 0 this creates a J distribution which whose effect can be seen in the attached graph.
[image]
My question is therefore: As the distribution is not normal, what methods can I use to state with 95% confidence that the aggregate availability of the whole fleet in any given year will be X% or higher, given that the data is non normal?

One solution might be to use bootstrapping. e.g. For a 10 machine fleet

1. Take 10*12 random samples find the mean for the fleets ‘machine
2. months’  repeat lots of times
3. find the confidence interval of the mean.

Would this give a result that was meaningful?

The assumptions that I am making are

- The machines are all identical.
- There are no significant downtimem differences between machines.
- There are no significant downtime differences between months.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, the bootstrapping approach you describe should be fine.

Comment: You need to add one more assumption: that the monthly availabilities are statistically independent. This is important enough to be worth checking before you proceed.

Comment: As an alternative to bootstrapping, you could look into using the beta distribution.